# Do we really need to replace & with &amp in URLs?

Tags: php, url, standards, ampersand

I am using a validation tool and it is returning errors that the page has parsing errors `Found '&'. You should use '&amp;' instead` found in php-style links (i.e. `< a href="index.php?route=home&path=1">` is incorrect whereas `< a href="index.php?route=home&amp;path=1">` is considered correct). What standards does this break?  I thought it was normal practice to use & in URLs.  The website is written in PHP.

Please note that I am not looking for support on the software.  I'm just curious to know what part of the standards I may be breaking.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with accessibility or URLs.

`&` is a special character in HTML which means "start of entity".

To say "An ampersand" instead of "Start of entity" in HTML you should use the entity for ampersand: `&amp;`.

There are times when you can use a raw `&` in HTML, but it is simplest to always use `&amp;` instead of trying to remember the times when it is optional.

(Exception: You must use a raw `&` are inside `<script>` and `<style>` elements.)

Comment: I should have been more specific - the errors being returned are only the ones that appear within php type links.  i.e. `index.php?route=home&path=1` - edited above

Comment: @Paul — So? That's an ampersand in HTML. The fact it is an ampersand in a URL in HTML is beside the point. `index.php?route=home&amp;path=1 `. It's even called out explicitly in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2